# Sharing CrunchyData Postgres Operator Secrets Between Namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-namespace, crunchy-postgresql-operator

I am using [CrunchyData Postgres Operator](https://github.com/CrunchyData/postgres-operator) to manage postgres databases on my Kubernetes cluster. This cluster will host multiple databases used by many projects.

I have set up the operator and a `PostgresCluster` named `postgres` on the namespace `postgres-operator`

Now, I am deploying a Laravel application, in the namespace `rates` that would need access to the database with the user `rates` and DB `rates`

Using CrunchyData helm chart, I have the following in `values.yaml` :

```
users: [
  {
    name: "rates",
    databases: ["rates"],
  }
]
```

Which creates the secret `postgres-pguser-rates` in the namespace `postgres-operator`

In my Laravel `Deployement`, I have the following in my yaml **environment** section:

```
            - name: DB_HOST
              valueFrom: { secretKeyRef: { name: postgres-pguser-rates, key: host } }
            - name: DB_PORT
              valueFrom: { secretKeyRef: { name: postgres-pguser-rates, key: port } }
            - name: DB_DATABASE
              valueFrom: { secretKeyRef: { name: postgres-pguser-rates, key: dbname } }
            - name: DB_USERNAME
              valueFrom: { secretKeyRef: { name: postgres-pguser-rates, key: user } }
            - name: DB_PASSWORD
              valueFrom: { secretKeyRef: { name: postgres-pguser-rates, key: password } }
```

Which basically accesses the secret the Postgres operator creates.

**The problem:** since my Laravel deployement and my postgres cluster live in different namespaces, the operator creates the secret in the namespace `postgres-operator` , and I am trying to access it from the deployment on the namespace `rates`

I have tried using Role, RoleBinding, and RBAC features in Kubernetes. But since I am trying to access the secret from the yaml file to setup environment variables, this method doesn't work.

I tried exploring [kubernetes-reflector](https://github.com/emberstack/kubernetes-reflector), however, since the operator cannot be modified to setup labels on the secrets it generates, this method doesn't work

I have 2 questions:

1. **Mainly, how to access the DB secret create by the operator from different namespaces?**
2. Or, would it be better deploying a separate DB cluster for each project? It seems to be too resource intensive for a lot of simple projects.

Answer (score 2):

> how to access the DB secret create by the operator from different namespaces?

As you have discovered, this isn't an RBAC issue; fundamentally, the `envFrom`/`valueFrom`/etc directives don't support referencing secrets in another namespace. The only way to get what you want is to ensure your application and the secrets are in the same namespace.

I think your idea using kubernetes-reflector looks like a good one. It would involve manually labelling the secrets after they have been created, but that's fine; you're going to have to select which secrets get placed in which namespace *somehow*, and this seems reasonable.

If you're consistently naming things so that secret `postgres-pguser-<name>` should be exposed in namespace `<name>`, then you could write your own operator that watches for secrets matching that pattern and then copies them to the appropriate namespace. The [operator sdk](https://sdk.operatorframework.io/) makes this relatively easy; you could also accomplish the same thing with a shell script that runs `kubectl get secret --watch`. Something like:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z "$WATCH_NAMESPACE" ]]; then
  echo "ERROR: WATCH_NAMESPACE is undefined." >&2
  exit 1
fi

while :; do

  # watch for secret create/update/delete
  kubectl -n "$WATCH_NAMESPACE" get secret -o name --watch | while read -r thing; do

    # extract name from "secret/<name>"
    name=${thing#*/}
    echo "found secret name: $name"

    # check if it matches specific pattern
    if [[ $name = postgres-pguser-* ]]; then

      # extract namespace from secret name
      target_ns=${name##*-}

      if kubectl -n "$WATCH_NAMESPACE" get secret "$name" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        # copy secret to target namespace

        echo "  copy to $target_ns"
        kubectl -n "$WATCH_NAMESPACE" get secret "$name" -o json |
          jq 'del(.metadata.namespace, .metadata.uid, .metadata.resourceVersion)' |
          kubectl -n "$target_ns" apply -f-
      else
        # delete secret from target namespace

        echo "  delete from $target_ns"
        kubectl -n "$target_ns" delete secret "$name"
      fi
    fi
  done
  sleep 1
done
```

Run that in a Pod with appropriate permissions and it should do what you want.

> Or would it be better deploying a separate DB cluster for each project? It seems to be too resource intensive for a lot of simple projects.

I think this would be a much more common configuration.

Depending on the nature of your simple projects, it may make more sense to just deploy a stock postgres container rather than using all the features offered by the crunchy postgres operator.

Answer (score 0):

In the namespace where your application resides, you can reference the secret by specifying both the namespace and the secret name. For example, if the secret is in the namespace-1 namespace and has the name db-credentials, you can reference it in namespace-2 as follows:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
name: your-app
namespace: namespace-2
spec:
template:
spec:
containers:
- name: your-app-container
image: your-app-image
env:
- name: DB_USERNAME
valueFrom:
secretKeyRef:
name: db-credentials
key: username
- name: DB_PASSWORD
valueFrom:
secretKeyRef:
name: db-credentials
key: password